# getting error in running Webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

running **webpack-dev-server** gets following error.

```
const options = wpOpt.devServer || firstWpOpt.devServer || {};
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'devServer' of undefined
    at processOptions (E:\repos\ng4-ngcli-server-test\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:208:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\repos\ng4-ngcli-server-test\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:430:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

webpack version.

```
webpack-dev-server 2.4.2
webpack 2.4.1
```

npm & node version.

```
npm -> 3.10.8
node -> 6.9.1
```

Comment: Share your webpack.config.js

Comment: sounds like firstWpOpt variable doesn´t exists. But yes, sharing your config file will help